# How To Inline text that breaks into multiple lines - Respect Padding

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a text effect with a background that spans the width of each line of text, similar to the one shown in this image:

[image]

I've tried using *display: inline* as suggested in some tutorials, but I couldn't get the desired result. the result of *display: inline* didn't preserve the padding

I want the text on one element - Dynamic Text.

```html
<h1> improving Tech Business Planning </h1>
```

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this effect properly? I want the background color to wrap along with the text on each line, and also, it should respect any padding around the text.

Thank you!

```css
body {
background: black;
margin: 2rem;
}
h1 {
  background: white;
  display: inline;
  padding: 2rem 2rem
}
```

```html
 <h1
    class="main-title"
  >
    improving tech business planning
  </h1>
```

Comment: _"the result of display: inline didn't preserve the padding"_ - [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) helps with that.

Comment: This problem will solve with box-decoration-break

you can learn more from there https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-decoration-break/